# How to correctly execute a function JS with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a function by clicking on a span, but it tells me that it is undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function callTo(param) {
    alert(param);
  }
});
```

```css
.file-up {
  background: #f5f5f5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #383f45;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="file-up" onclick="callTo('test')">Click to call</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Better way is use addEventListener('click', () => {}) than onclick

Comment: `callTo` is only available in the anonymous function you're passing to `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: `callTo` is hidden inside the function scope of the `ready` callback, it's never exported.

Comment: And how should I proceed if my function should be able to be executed in different HTML elements with different parameters? I mean, I was using onclick that way, since +15 elements must be able to execute that function with their own parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        sample
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function callTo(param) {
            alert(param);
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <span class="file-up" id="index" onclick="callTo('test')">
            Click to call
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is a working example without using jQuery, just by vanilla javascript. Insert it and use it directly.
If you want me to post an answer which uses only jQuery for the stated task that you want to accomplish then please let me know.

This is code using jQuery, as you asked -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        sample
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#index').click (function callTo() {
        alert("Your values is :"+ $(this).data("value"));
      });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <span class="file-up" id="index" data-value="test">
        Click to call
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Greetings, I would like to see the show with jquery

Comment: Okay, no problem, but, first tell me this, Is my logic correct ?, Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes, I just tried as you say and it works for my case

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your function definition away from $(documents).ready

```
<script>
    function callTo(param) {
        alert(param);
    }
</script>
```

Or define event listener like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.file-up').click(function() {
            //action
        });
    });
</script>
```

(I'd better give it an id in this case and change the selector to `#id` instead of `.file-up` because other elements can have the same class applied)